# Galvanic cell of zinc half cell and copper half cell

Tags: chemical-potential, electrochemistry, displacement-current

Where do the $Zn^{+2}$ ions come from in a $Zn$-half cell, if from zinc metal then why doesn't after some time $Zn$ metal is completely vanished and what is the purpose of $Zn^{+2}$ ions of zinc sulphate electrolyte?

Answer (score 1):

In a $|Zn/Cu|$ galvanic cell **two** reactions take place.

**1. Oxidation of zinc metal:**

$$Zn(s) \to Zn^{2+}(aq) + 2 e^-$$

**2. Reduction of cupric ions:**

$$Cu^{2+}(aq) + 2 e^- \to Cu(s)$$

During operation (closed circuit) anode zinc metal is constantly dissolved to form a zinc salt (usually zinc sulphate) and copper metal is being electroplated at the cathode from copper sulphate.

Allow the cell to run for long enough and the zinc anode will indeed have been consumed completely.

Both half-cells need a salt solution (usually zinc sulphate and copper sulphate, respectively) in order for the cell to be conductive: that's the meaning of the word *electrolyte*: a conductive solution.